# Does the Kotlin "when" expression support compound boolean expression when using a subject?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to provide a compound boolean expression in the `when(subject) { ... }` block?

The following will not compile

```kotlin
val num: Any = 2
when(num) {
    /* compound boolean expression that uses implicit subject expression
     * and an independent expression */
    is Number && true -> println("TRUE")
    else -> println("FALSE")
}
```

The following will compile, but results in `FALSE`. Is this the expected behavior?

```kotlin
val num: Any = 2
when(num) {
    num is Number && true -> println("TRUE")
    else -> println("FALSE")
}
```

I have a long list of *when* conditions and most of them only use the implicit subject but a couple need secondary conditions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the first one: looking at the [`when` grammar](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#when) it is intended. Only `in` and `is` (and their negative counterparts) are allowed directly. Otherwise you only have expressions.

Now regarding your second one it may help to transform it to an `if`/`else`-statement first. Basically your `when` will look as follows then:

```
if (num == ((num is Number) && true)) println("TRUE")
else println("FALSE")
```

If looking at this it becomes clear why it always prints `FALSE`. While `num is Number` becomes `true` and `true && true` is still `true`, the `num == true` is false as `num` isn't even a boolean ;-)

Or in other words: your "subject" in the `when` is compared against each of the conditions (thanks [Bwvolleyball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3859199/bwvolleyball) for the comment).

---

What however I don't really understand (but that could also be my misunderstanding of the grammar)... looking at the grammar it seems as if the following would be possible:

```
when {
  is Number -> TODO()
}
```

but as one could expect: it doesn't... but the last statement is rather a side-note.

Comment: To add to this, it's the fact that Kotlin is comparing the item in the `when()` clause with the items being switched on. This example will always print 'two':

    `val num = 2
    when(num) {
      num2.equals(num2) -> println("true")
      num2 -> println("two")
      else -> println("false")
    }`

because like OP mentioned, `num == true` (we get true from `num2.equals(num2)`) is false, and so it gets skipped.

Sorry about the format, there is no good way to do it in a comment...

Answer (score 20):

```
//First case
//Prints TRUE if the num value is numeric and true.Anything else prints FALSE
 val num: Any = 2
    when {
        num is Number && true -> println("TRUE")
        else -> println("FALSE")
    }
//Second case
//Prints true if the value is numeric OR true.Anything else prints FALSE
val num: Any = 2
when(num){
         is Number , true -> println("TRUE")
        else -> println("FALSE")
    }
```

Comment: explain why this is the answer.

Comment: This is actually my first ever comment so take my mistakes in consideration.If the 'num' variable takes a true or numeric value it will print true everything else will return false. For example if you put a string or a false value at 'num' will return false.But I am not sure about the &&. Because the 'num' value will take either a numeric value or a boolean the && is unnecessary. In my opinion you can write it like this.
'val num: Any = 1 when(num){is Number , true -> println("TRUE") else -> println("FALSE")}'This checks if the num is either true or a number and returns true.

Comment: add it to your answer to make it better

Comment: Hi Mehrad. Thank you for guiding me. I really appreciate it. I edited my answer. I also made a comment but I don't see it for some reason.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - a `when` with multiple checks on a case. Similar to what you can do with the Swift `switch` statement.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it possible to provide multiple boolean conditions when using a `when(subject) { ... }` expression?

Yes, you can separate multiple [*when conditions*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#whenEntry) using a `,` (comma).

For instance, the following `when`s have the exact same behavior. [Runnable playground demo here](https://pl.kotl.in/0volKETvk).

```kotlin
fun withoutComma(arg: Any?): String {
  return when(arg) {
    is String -> "FOO!"  // returned when arg is an instance of String
    true -> "bar!"       // returned when arg == true
    is Long -> "FOO!"    // returned when arg is an instance of Long
    false -> "bar!"      // returned when arg == false
    null -> "FOO!"       // returned when arg == null
    is Int -> "bar!"     // returned when arg is an instance of Int
    else -> "else!"
  }
}

fun withComma(arg: Any?): String {
  return when(arg) {
    is String, is Long, null -> "FOO!"  // returned when arg is an instance of String, or when arg is an instance of Long, or when arg == null
    true, false, is Int -> "bar!"       // returned when arg == true, or when arg == false, or when arg is an instance of Int
    else -> "else!"
  }
}

fun main() {
    listOf("s", true, 999L, false, null, 123, emptyList<Any>()).forEach {
        println("$it -> withoutComma: ${withoutComma(it)}")
        println("$it -> withComma: ${withComma(it)}")
    }
}

// Prints:
// s -> withoutComma: FOO!
// s -> withComma: FOO!
// true -> withoutComma: bar!
// true -> withComma: bar!
// 999 -> withoutComma: FOO!
// 999 -> withComma: FOO!
// false -> withoutComma: bar!
// false -> withComma: bar!
// null -> withoutComma: FOO!
// null -> withComma: FOO!
// 123 -> withoutComma: bar!
// 123 -> withComma: bar!
// [] -> withoutComma: else!
// [] -> withComma: else!
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have multiple conditions for the when statement to evaluate, you can also create a new variable and check all your cases when assigning it a value. It’s not always the best case if you’re working on a very large app and have to be conscious about memory, but it makes your code much more readable and concise

ex:

```
/*
Num is evaluated for whether it is greater than, less than, or equal to 0 
and the corresponding String value is assigned to isNumberPositiveNegativeOrZero.
*/

val isNumberPositiveNegativeOrZero: String = when {
    num > 0 -> “number is positive”
    num < 0 -> “number is negative”
    else -> “number is zero”
}
```

This can, of course, be expanded into however many cases you want to check.
(This is my first time answering a question on here so please excuse any accidents)